# Create field in xsl-fo where image signature with PdfStamper will be placed

Tags: itext, xsl-fo

I need to create a placeholder (sign1) in xsl-fo so that the produced pdf could be signed in a proper place afterwards.

To sign I use iText:

```
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance....
appearance.setVisibleSignature("sign1");
appearance.setImage(image);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'a placeholder'?  Is it an area of defined size?  An ID?  Both?  Something else?

Comment: Whatever placehold you could possibly recommend, whatever in xsl which could be "visible" by appearance. Any help appreciated, now I use special character in xsl and in signing procecedure I search its location by TextMarginFinder and there I paste the signature image afterwards. Is there a better approach?